# FFMPEG Decoding - Memory Leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, ffmpeg

Developing an application for a test, I encountered an error. Meanwhile the packets were proccessed, I got a very horrible problem, a memory leak.

The av_free_packet is applied correctly, I think (See the code). When I run the app, the memory grows up to 500MB meanwhile it's playing the audio file, that's not normal. VLC or WMplayer (Windows Media Player) just wastes 30/20mb reading that file.

Here is the code:

```
static AVPacket pkt;
static uint8_t *audio_pkt_data = NULL;
static int audio_pkt_size = 0;
static AVFrame frame;
static bool first_time = true;

if(first_time){
    first_time=false;
}

int len1, data_size = 0;

for(;;){
    bool do_rt = false;

    while(audio_pkt_size > 0){
        int obt_frame = 0;

        len1 = avcodec_decode_audio4(_audio_ccontext,&frame,&obt_frame,&pkt);
        if(len1 < 0){
            audio_pkt_size = 0;
            break;
        }
        audio_pkt_data+=len1;
        audio_pkt_size-=len1;
        if(obt_frame){
            data_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL,channel_count,sample_fr,_audio_ccontext->sample_fmt,1);
            memcpy((int16_t*)audio_buf,frame.data[0],data_size);

        }
        if(data_size <= 0){
            continue;
        }
        do_rt = true;
    }

    if(pkt.data){
        //MessageBox(0,"hi","Hi",MB_OK); // This is only for test if the app si reaching this av_free_packet
        av_free_packet(&pkt);
    }

    if(do_rt){
        return data_size;
    }

    // Try to get a new packet
    if(!audio_packets.empty()){
        WaitForSingleObject(Queue_Audio_Mutex,INFINITE);
            pkt = *audio_packets.front();
            audio_packets.pop();
        ReleaseMutex(Queue_Audio_Mutex);

        audio_pkt_size = pkt.size;
        audio_pkt_data = pkt.data;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to free frame too. As per ffmpeg reference

[avcodec_decode_audio4()](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga834bb1b062fbcc2de4cf7fb93f154a3e)

The decoder will allocate a buffer for the decoded frame by calling the AVCodecContext.get_buffer2() callback. When AVCodecContext.refcounted_frames is set to 1, the frame is reference counted and the returned reference belongs to the caller. The caller must release the frame using av_frame_unref() when the frame is no longer needed. Please follow the link.
You can try adding

```
av_frame_unref(&frame)
```

Comment: My app is crashing when I do that